# Welcome to Cubing

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, rubiks-cube

After the critical feedback on [the previous question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36766/how-many-cubes-can-we-fit-in), here is the new question...

> It so happened that one day, your nephew came to you and said that he wanted you to play a **board** game with you. You were getting **bored** so you agreed.
>   The only problem was that you had no dice to play with and neither did he; so you wrote numbers from $[1,6]$ on each central piece of your solved [3x3x3 Rubik's cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik's_Cube).
>
> When you were done playing with him, you thought of writing more numbers on it. You wondered on how many possible combinations are there with the following constraints:

Constraints:

1. The original numbering on the cube follows the standard of a regular dice, i.e. the sum of the numbers on opposite faces is seven.
2. Each piece surrounding the central piece, with number $N$ is to be numbered in range $[0,N]$.
3. No two sides of an edge piece, or a corner piece should have the same number.

---

How many such combinations are possible (if any)?

---

[image: A brief about Rubik's cube]

Image credits: http://www.cse.iitm.ac.in/~kalyantv/pdf/Rubix_cube_solution.pdf

Comment: Do the edge and corner pieces also have to sum to 7?

Comment: No, there is no such restriction. But I do feel that a computer program can be made to calculate if that were the case :)

Comment: No computer program necessary---in that case the only valid solutions would be each face composed entirely of the same number, and there would only be two solutions (modulo rotation).

Comment: The sum constraint is only because of the nature of a dice, so only central pieces are fixed (as in the sum on the opposite central pieces sums up to 7).

Comment: @2012rcampion That is a brilliantly simple, and correct, solution for that case :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the total number of such configurations is

> $240\,734\,712\,102\,912\,000\,000\,000\,000$ (240 septillion)

Reasoning:

> Each corner piece will be between three center pieces, none of which oppose each other (i.e. sum to 7), thus there will always be a corner which is between centers 1,2 and 3, another corner between 1,2 and 4, a third one between 1,3 and 5, and so on.
>
>  But how many different ways are there to write valid numbers for the individual corners?
>  The corner between centers 1,2,3 can take the following numbers: 0,1,2; 0,1,3; 0,2,1; 0,2,3; 1,0,2; 1,0,3; 1,2,0; 1,2,3 - that's 8 different numberings, but how to generalize?
>
>  The side of the corner towards the center with the smallest number (let's call that number $N_1$) can take any value from $0$ to $N_1$, that's $N_1+1$ choices.
>  The side towards the second smallest center (which is $N_2$) can take any value from $0$ to $N_2$, except the one which was written to the previous side.   That's $N_2+1-1=N_2$ choices.
>  The third side, towards the center with the largest value ($N_3$) can take values between $0$ and $N_3$, but neither of the previous two different values, so there are $N_3+1-2=N_3-1$ choices.
>  So a corner piece between centers $N_1 < N_2 < N_3$ can have $(N_1+1) \times N_2 \times (N_3-1)$ valid numberings.
>
>  So the different numberings of the different corners are the following:
>  (neighbouring centers : number of numberings)
>  1 2 3 : 8
>  1 2 4 : 12
>  1 3 5 : 24
>  1 4 5 : 32
>  2 3 6 : 45
>  2 4 6 : 60
>  3 5 6 : 100
>  4 5 6 : 125
>
>  A very similar reasoning holds for the edge pieces, which only have two sides (towards centers $N_1 < N_2$, when $N_1+N_2 \ne 7$), so the expression also changes to $(N_1+1) \times N_2$:
>  1 2 : 4
>  1 3 : 6
>  1 4 : 8
>  1 5 : 10
>  2 3 : 9
>  2 4 : 12
>  2 6 : 18
>  3 5 : 20
>  3 6 : 24
>  4 5 : 25
>  4 6 : 30
>  5 6 : 36
>
>  All these pieces can be numbered independently from each other, so to get the correct solution we just have to multiply all these numbers together. Also there is a factor of 2 (which I first forgot about) from the center pieces being a right-1,2,3 or a left-1,2,3 rotation.